# AngularJS - Where to define angular module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, module, controller

Suppose my angular js app(myApp) has a controller and directive, How would I be declaring both?

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myController"......

angular.module("myApp")
.directive("myDirective".......

OR

angular.module("myApp",[])
.directive("myDirective".......

angular.module("myApp")
.controller("myController"......
```

If you see the above code, I am defining my angular app on a controller, and then just retrieving it for the directive. In the second case, I am defining my app for a directive, and retrieving it for a controller.

Which is the right way? How to decide on what is the correct way?

Comment: i think you need read this. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. It doesn't affect the way the application is bootstrapped.

You only need to understand what `angular.module()` does.

`angular.module("myApp",[])` creates a new AngularJS module named "myApp" with the dependencies passed as the second parameter.

`angular.module("myApp")` is a getter. It returns the module if it has been created before.

Both return the same object. So then, you can add your directives and controllers in the order you want.

Once everything is loaded, AngularJS starts the bootstrapping process. See the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).